# react 16, render with array, with first and last element conditiona with divl in complex render

Tags: reactjs

I have a render that returns array and it's working well, it's iterate over an array to show fields in a form. But now i Want to enclose in a divs to group some fields conditionnaly accord to a propery. to get somethi like

```
<div class='section>
   <Field>
   <Field>
</div>
<div class='section>
   <Field>
</div>
```

actually i get just:

```
<div class='section>
   <Field>
   <Field>
</div>
```

One example of a branch in my object:
(it's when the field have "formNewSection" property to separate the fields grouped by div)

```
    "identitydocs": {
        "type": "String",
        "dbtype": "Json",
        "labelChildsGlobal": true,
        "labelChildsShow": true,
        "subfields": {
            "id": {
                "type": "ID",
                "typeInput": "hidden"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "String",
                "label": "id_doctype"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "String",
                "validators": [
                    "required"
                ],
                "typeInput": "selectBox",
                "listSource": "countries"
            },
            "number": {
                "type": "String",
                "label": "id_docnumber"
            },
            "idnameisother": {
                "type": "Boolean",
                "typeInput": "checkbox",
                "formNewSection": true
            },
            "lastname": {
                "type": "String",
                "validators": [
                    "required",
                    "alphai18n",
                    "minLength:3"
                ],
                "normalize": "UpperCase"
            },
            "firstname": {
                "type": "String",
                "validators": [
                    "required",
                    "alphai18n",
                    "minLength:3"
                ]
            },
            "idexpiration": {
                "type": "String",
                "dbtype": "Date"
            },
            "idiauthority": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ididate": {
                "type": "String",
                "dbtype": "Date"
            },
            "idaddressisother": {
                "type": "Boolean",
                "typeInput": "checkbox",
                "formNewSection": true
            },
            "addressline1": {
                "type": "String",
                "validators": [
                    "required"
                ]
            },
            "addressline2": {
                "type": "String",
                "validators": [
                    "required"
                ]
            },
            "cp": {
                "type": "String",
                "inputSize": 7
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "cityid": {
                "type": "ID",
                "typeInput": "hidden"
            }
        }
    },
```

My code working:

```
      return [
        <Field
          key={index+'-'+subindex+'-'+fieldKey}
          name={`${rowValues}.${fieldKey}`}
          type={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
          typeInput={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
          component={FormField}
          label={field.labelChildsShow ? t(labelKey ):''}
          placeHolder={!field.labelChildsShow || subfield.placeHolder ? t(labelKey) : ''}
          listSource={subfield.listSource ? aSources[subfield.listSource] : ''}
          index={subindex + 1}
          width="270px"
          icon={subfield.icon}
        />,
        fields.length === 1 && subindex + 1 === Object.keys(Tables[tableCrud].fields[fieldParentKey].subfields).length ?
          <div key={index+'-'+subindex+'-b'} style={ { marginTop: "10px", marginRight: "5px" } }><a href="#" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
            <ShowIcon size="25" color="gray" icon="removecircleblack"/>
          </a></div>
          : null,
      ];
```

My new codigo does not work, adding  and  on the top and botomm of array but conditionnaly:

```
return [
                (subfield.formNewSection && <div className="formSubSection" >),
                <Field
                  key={index+'-'+subindex+'-'+fieldKey}
                  name={`${rowValues}.${fieldKey}`}
                  type={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
                  typeInput={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
                  component={FormField}
                  label={field.labelChildsShow ? t(labelKey ):''}
                  placeHolder={!field.labelChildsShow || subfield.placeHolder ? t(labelKey) : ''}
                  listSource={subfield.listSource ? aSources[subfield.listSource] : ''}
                  index={subindex + 1}
                  width="270px"
                  icon={subfield.icon}
                />,
                (fields.length === 1 && subindex + 1 === Object.keys(Tables[tableCrud].fields[fieldParentKey].subfields).length ?
                  <div key={index+'-'+subindex+'-b'} style={ { marginTop: "10px", marginRight: "5px" } }><a href="#" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
                    <ShowIcon size="25" color="gray" icon="removecircleblack"/>
                  </a></div>
                  : null)
                  (subfield.formNewSection && </div>),
       ];
```

with this modificaiotn i get print "fields.length === 1 && subindex + 1 === ..." on the screen.

is possible to do what i'm looking for with react? I can't do it in a simple way, becase this render is inside another render do it with .map, some fields have a mark to be grouped by divs and anothers not, so i can't see for the simple solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide the array structure or the real data for the data I'll take a look and see If I can help you with that.

One idea is suppose you had a a data structure housing the the items with index or a length that is equivalent to the fields something like this:
{
0: [ ... ,  ]
... to whatever data length
} <-- this can be an array instead of object
iterate over this container/w.e and have a div surrounding it

pending if you used array or object if object you can use Object.keys(w.e)
like poopArrayContainer.map( (item,ind) =>  { item.map( poop => ... ) }  ) ... pretty sure you get it from here hope that helps, not sure of that's the best implementation but that's a thot LuL...

Comment: if you need help or anything is unclear feel free to comment here :D

Comment: i'v just updated my answer, maybe i need to pre process the array to get a new arra like you suggest in by example groups [  {groupfields1}, {groupfields2}, it's seems react dont' accept just a single <div> open , without </div>

Comment: Hey Dave ya by all mean preprocess all the info you need to fit the structure of what needs to be done :)

For example if you just apply the logic to create an array that fits the structure of what i needed then im pretty sure you will arrive to your answer but at all costs try to do it in the backend that way the cpu processing is not handled on the front end.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just add the div tag before the field one and at the end like :

```
        <div className="formSubSection" > <Field.......
    .. 
        </a></div></div>
        : null)
```

Comment: sorry but this render is complex, fields have aleatory subfield.formNewSection propery, and this render is inside another render loop